# Problem Solving with a Trapezium - NEED HELP

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

In a trapezium PQRS, PQ is parallel to SR and ∠SPQ = ∠RQP = 135°. The trapezium contains an inscribed circle and the length of PQ is 1 cm. What is the exact length of QR?
Need Urgently. Thanks

Comment: are you sure that angle SPQ and angle RQP same?

Comment: Yes they definitely are

Comment: Please, don't use "urgent need". You have already used it in your other question. Imagine that everybody could use it. Moreover it is counterproductive: don't imagine answers will come in a quicker way because you have added such a pressure. On the contrary...

Comment: Ok sorry will take that into consideration next time thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the following figure: 
[image]

The radius of circle can be calculated from the small right triangle as :

$$\tan\left(\frac{135^\circ}{2}\right) = \frac{2r}{PQ} = 2r$$

Then QR is simply $2\sqrt{2}r$

Comment: and is this radius known?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Now? yes.